# How to add a comma to the last character of a line in a textfile

Tags: regex, line, replace

I have a very long text file full of email adresses, from an export of a newsletter db. To import them in another system I need to have these adresses separated by a comma.

I'm trying to do a search/replace using regex. So far I can find the last character of each line with :

```
[^\n]$
```

So that's for my "Search" field. But I don't know with what to put into "Replace". I'm very new to regex, is there a wildcard that would allow to do something like :

```
[any characted found],
```

Comment: short answer: yes, what you want can definitely be done. But first, please give some more info: what program are you using to do the search and replace? Different regex flavours have subtly different syntax (or sometimes not so subtle). See http://www.regular-expressions.info/ for lots of info. And what's the exact format of your file, is it one email address per line, or is there some other separator between addresses?

Comment: I use Geany on Linux (ubuntu), and the file is a text file, each email address is on one line, no space a the end, only separator is a line break.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could search for `([^\n])$` and replace it by `\1,` – depending on your RegEx engine.

Comment: You're welcome! The trick was that `()` creates a group of characters that can later be used when replacing by referencing each group by its place in the regex, i.e. \1 is the first captured group, \2 the second and so on.

Answer (score 6):

Look into sed...

```
sed 's/$/,/' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -pe 's/$/,/'⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠ ⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠ ⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠
```